# importing excel's time field to mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to import an excel file into a MySQL database using `PHPExcel`.
Everything is basically working well except for the time fields that are in excel.

They are stored in numbers like 0.58333333333333, 0.45833333333333...

Would appreciate any help to understanding how excel stores this and how to convert this to a time data that can be stored in a MYSQL table?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's full hours you have in the sheet you can just `$val*24`. https://3v4l.org/7OJjQ probably faster than using phpexcel to do it. If it's not full hours it's a mess to convert manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel stores a float count of whole days, so 0.5 is half a day (12 hours), 0.25 is a quarter of a day (6 hours), etc.

You can convert this value to a unix timestamp or a PHP DateTime object using PHPExcel's built-in date/time handling functions:

```
$cellValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C12')->getValue();
$unixTimestamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cellValue);
echo date('H:i:s', $unixTimestamp);
```

or

```
$cellValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C12')->getValue();
$dateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($cellValue);
echo $dateTimeObject->format('H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can use Excel's `TEXT` function to convert Excel's numeric date-time value to a text string in the date format expected and insert it into SQL later.